# getting StripeInvalidRequestError: No such payment_intent: 'pi_3LVwOn4IimzjyVut1GNg6Urh' when stripe.paymentIntents.confirm

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I want to use OptionalHandle the Alipay redirect manually, but get StripeInvalidRequestError: No such payment_intent: 'pi_3LVwOn4IimzjyVut1GNg6Urh'

```
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
      {
        payment_method_types: ['alipay'],
        amount: 1000,
        currency: 'hkd',
        application_fee_amount: 0,
      },
      {
        stripeAccount: connectedStripeAccountId,
      },
    );

    const comfirmpaymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(
      paymentIntent.id,
      {
        return_url: 'https://....',
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re creating a [Direct Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges) `PaymentIntent` on the Connect Account but when you’re confirming that `PaymentIntent` you’re using not passing the `stripeAccount` id the same way you did for the creation. What happens is that `Stripe` will try to look at the PaymentIntent in your Platform Account and it’s not finding it. If you don’t have a logic between creating the PaymentIntent and confirming it, you could always pass `confirm: true` [param](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-confirm)  when creating the `PaymentIntent`.